# Creating second model upon instantiation of the first within sqlachemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am currently working with some legacy code that looks as follows:

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import Unicode
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import ARRAY, TEXT

Base = declarative_base()

class Book(Base):

    __tablename__ = 'book'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = Column(Unicode)
    keywords = Column('keywords', ARRAY(TEXT), primary_key=False)
```

The keywords are currently being kept as an array, but I'd like to flatten this out and have them be in their own separate model

```
class Keyword():

    __tablename__ = 'keyword'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    book_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('book.id', ondelete='cascade'),
        nullable=False)
    keyword = Column(Unicode)
```

How can I make it such that when a Book() is created, it also creates the 
accompanying keywords? As an intermediate step for migrating the API, I'd like to keep the current array column, but also have the accompanying Keyword() instances be created.

I could do this within an `__init__` method, but would need to know what the current Session() was, in order to run a commit. I could also perhaps use a `property` attribute, attached to `keywords`, but am not sure how that would work given that I am working with a class that inherits from SQLAlchemy's base, and not with a regular class that I have defined. What's the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`object_session`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.session.object_session) to find out the session of a given instance.

But if you define relationship between a `Book` and `Keywords`, you should not need even bother:

```
class Book(Base):
    # ...
    rel_keywords = relationship('Keyword', backref='book')

    def init_keyword_relationship(self):
        for kw in self.keywords:
            self.rel_keywords.add(Keyword(keyword=kw))


sess = # ... get_session...
books = sess.query(Book).all()
for book in books:
    book.init_keyword_relationship()
sess.commit()
```

However, I would do a migration once and get rid of the `keywords` array in order not to add a logic to keep those in sync.